# Sending data from HTML form to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I am trying to send form data via ajax to a nodejs server.

Here's what my code looks like (EDITED):

```
<div id="inputid" style="width: 400px; height:400px">
    <p> Please enter the respective values in each field and hit Submit </p>
    <form id="sendCoordinates" action="http://localhost:8080/geodata" method="post"> 
    MinLat: <input type="text" name="MinLat" id="minlat"><br>
    MaxLat: <input type="text" name="MaxLat" id="maxlat"><br>
    MinLong: <input type="text" name="MinLong" id="minlong"><br>
    MinLong: <input type="text" name="MaxLong" id="maxlong"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="s1">
    </form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(sendCoordinates)
        .on('success.form.fv', function(e) {
            // Prevent form submission
            e.preventDefault();

            var $form    = $(e.target),
                formData = new FormData(),
                params   = $form.serializeArray();

            $.each(params, function(i, val) {
                formData.append(val.name, val.value);
            });

            console.log(formData);

            $.ajax({
                url: $form.attr('action'),
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                }
            });
        });
});
</script>
```

My server side code looks like this :

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser"); 

var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Initialize the app.
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function () {
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log("App now running on port", port);
  });

// for debugging purposes, just logging the request to check
// if request received

app.post("/geodata", function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

I am trying this out but I am unable to send the form successfully, and upon hitting submit, nothing happens. I am not able to log the `formData` on the client side, neither am I able to log the output at the endpoint on the server side.

Can someone point out what I might be doing wrong? All I get is an empty {} when I hit submit. Is my `"action"` tag in my `form` pointing to the correct url for posting to the endpoint `/geodata`?

Comment: Your express route should be using `post` method like `app.post("/geodata...`

Comment: @Sami I am using app.post, it was a typo earlier. Nothing happens when I press submit.

Comment: `alert('Hi');` doesn't show? Have you waiting for document.ready?

Comment: 1) Check in the browser (e.g. chrome dev tools network tab) that your request is correct. 2) Check your server rest is working. You can use "Advanced REST client" chrome extension for example.

Comment: Another thing that you need to do is sending back your response e.g. res.send({}); and post with content-type: application/json

Comment: As @lastboy mentioned you should view your browser console logs. Further if you are doing node app you can use debugger tools like node-inspector in future. After that being said, your ajax request syntax is wrong  . There is no chaining to catch. You can use `done`, `fail`, `always` for ajax request refer http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ or if you want to use `then` then refer https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/ for correct syntax.

Comment: Changing input type to submit instead of button might help.

Comment: I have changed things as recommended in these comments. However, I still am not able to get the form data to the server. Can anyone point out if I am posting to the correct url?