# Unable to send form data to server side (nodejs) using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, forms

I am trying to send form data via ajax to a nodejs server. Previously asked on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36303084/sending-data-from-html-form-to-server?noredirect=1#comment60233737_36303084).

Here's what my code looks like:

```
<div id="inputid" style="width: 400px; height:400px">
    <p> Please enter a value between -90 and 90 for lat, and -180 and 180 before hitting
        submit.</p>
    <form id="sendCoordinates" action="http://localhost:8080/geodata" method="post"> 
    MinLat: <input type="text" name="MinLat" value="15" id="minlat"><br>
    MaxLat: <input type="text" name="MaxLat" value="25" id="maxlat"><br>
    MinLong: <input type="text" name="MinLong" value="-10" id="minlong"><br>
    MinLong: <input type="text" name="MaxLong" value="120" id="maxlong"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="s1">
    </form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("hi hi");
    $("#sendCoordinates")
        .on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $form    = $(e.target),
                formData = new FormData(),
                params   = $form.serializeArray();

            $.each(params, function(i, val) {
                // console.log(val);
                formData.append(val.name, val.value);
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: $form.attr('action'),
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(result) {
                    console.log("hi helo");
                }
            });
        });
});
</script>

</div>
```

My server side code looks like this :

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser"); 

var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Initialize the app.
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function () {
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log("App now running on port", port);
  });

// for debugging purposes, just logging the request to check
// if request received

app.post("/geodata", function(req, res) {
  console.log("hey");
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send("hi back!");
});
```

I am trying this out but I am unable to send the form successfully, and upon hitting submit, I get "hey" and an empty {} as logged output. I am not able to log the `formData` on the client side, regardless.

Can someone point out what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: For starters, `$(sendCoordinates)` should probably be `$("#sendCoordinates")`.

Comment: @Pointy thanks for pointing that out. Unfortunately, it doesn't fix the problem. :(

Comment: Where do you expect that "success" event to come from? If you want to handle the "submit" event, you should pass that to `.on()` instead.

Comment: @Pointy hmm, I have changed that to "submit" instead. It's still not sending the form data :/

Comment: You took out the `e.preventDefault()` call, so that's why you're getting two form posts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107781/discussion-between-newenthusiast-and-pointy).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't assign a `form` to `formData()` that's why you're not sending any data to the server.

```
var myForm = $('#sendCoordinates')[0];
var formData = new FormData(myForm);
```

Comment: That makes sense-- however, now I don't even see anything sent to the server with this change. :/

Comment: log `formData` after being populated and see if it is empty or not ?